# Chaincode installation fail on marbles example of Hyperledger - Promise is rejected: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: EOF

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to build a small blockchain demo using Hyperledger Fabric. More exactly I'm using the marbles demo as an example to write a code. The network initialization, channel artifacts generation and admin and user registering works properly.
The docker containers are all up and running:

```
Creating peer0.qui.hosp.com ... done
Creating peer0.don.hosp.com ... done
Creating orderer.hosp.com   ... done
Creating peer0.txa.hosp.com ... done
Creating peer0.cru.hosp.com ... done
Creating ca.cru.hosp.com    ... done
Creating cli                ... done
```

However, after successfully enrolling the admin and registering a user, when typing `node install_chaincode.js` from the marbles example to install the proper chaincode I get the following error.

```
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: EOF at new createStatusError (/home/VICOMTECH/xmorales/Hyper/Myproject/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)
at /home/VICOMTECH/xmorales/Hyper/Myproject/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:583:15
error: [fcw] Failed to obtain endorsement for transaction. code=14, , details=EOF
error: [fcw] Error in install catch block object code=14, , details=EOF
---------------------------------------
info: Install done. Errors: parsed=Blockchain network error - EOF,raw=[code=14, , details=EOF]
---------------------------------------
```

The marbles example worked properly but when including my own configuration to the files this is what I get. I changed all the config files that seemed to be needed for the `install_chaincode.js` script to work. I'm sorry if the post is quite rudimentary, it is my first time asking a question.

Comment: check for silly things, like some empty characters at the end of your file, carriage returns. remove anything unnecessary and try again.

Comment: @X.Morales Do u have solved the issue?

Comment: @malajisi No it wasn't but I'm not longer working on it anymore